# Ubuntu mySQL server administrator GUI - how can I view actual database tables data in the gui?

Tags: mysql, mysqladministrator

I can see the various dataabases ('catalogs'). I was hoping for the ability to also see a visual view of the data, similar to what I can get in pgadmin for postgres.
I know I can use the command prompt and I am confident in that.  However I would like to use a gui for ease of use when debugging and reviewing data in applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download phpMyadmin / mysql workbench free

Answer (score 1):

In terminal type `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`

Then goto `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` in browser

login using , `MySQL username & password`